# Why doesn't my object inherit the keys functions?

Tags: javascript

If I have an object:

```
A = {a:true}
```

Why do I have to use:

```
Object.keys(A)
```

and not:

```
A.keys()
```

If keys is a method of Object, and everything inherits from Object, shouldn't A be able to call keys?

Comment: Keys is a method of the `Object` *constructor*, but it is not a method of the `Object.prototype` exemplar that all objects inherit from.

Comment: Another logical reason is that the function should also work when retrieving all keys from this object: `{keys:''}`. Guess why it wouldn't work in your expected notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.keys` is a so-to-say "static" method attached strictly to the `Object` function, not to its instances.

For it to be inherited, it would need to be defined as `Object.prototype.keys`.

You can certainly add it yourself if you so desire:

```
Object.prototype.keys = function () {
    return Object.keys(this);
};
```

Just note, as [Rocket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket) mentioned in the comments, "own" properties take precedence over `prototype` properties:

```
var foo = {};
foo.keys(); // Array of enumerable key names, if any

var bar = { keys: true };
bar.keys(); // TypeError: not a function
```

Comment: Just note, if your object has a key called `keys`, this won't work.  `A = {keys: "test"};  A.keys; // "test"`.  This is why it's `Object.keys` :-P

Comment: I'm downvoting this for encouraging people to modify Object's prototype. I would strongly advise against modifying native object's prototypes and certainly that of Object itself. It's simply not good practice. I suspect you know that but forgot to mention it.

Comment: @speg The usual concern is with collisions -- there's only 1 `Object.prototype`, but you may want to use 2 scripts that each try to define `Object.prototype.foo` differently. One's going to lose to the other. Most other concerns that tend to get lumped in are usually [in regards to Host objects](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/), such as the various DOM interfaces, rather than native objects.

Comment: It's this that I would be more worried about: https://gist.github.com/1843911 By modifying Object.prototype, you are modifying the behaviour of *every* script that uses for..in on *any* object. I can't see how that's sensible.

Comment: @HowardYeend You can prevent that in at least 2 ways -- 1) use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) inside the `for..in` to filter (e.g. `if (bar.hasOwnProperty(prop))`) or, with ES5, 2) define it through [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to set `enumerable: false`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You can indeed. It's just not a nice thing to do. Do you really want to write code that unintentionally changes the way other scripts run? It creates a hostile environment. Moreover, regarding mitigation; in 1) Many many many people do not use hasOwnProperty habitually, and one shouldn't have to. As to 2) Well, your example didn't use this, nor is it a viable option for developers in many environments.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski changing built-in behavior has extremely high potential to negatively affect other third-party code, which rightly relies on built-in behavior being the way it normally is. I saw jquery fail (hard) on a page one time, and after 3 days of debugging, found out that it was because somewhere buried deep within thousands of lines of code, some idiot dev had modified the Array prototype to add an incompatible/incorrect definition of .push()... This causes jquery's selector engine to fail. There are thousands of similar war stories that prove what you're suggesting is poor form.

Comment: @speg I must admit, I was hoping this argument had come to a rest. :) But alas, I'll add this: it depends on your team and intended audience. I still can't agree with Howard and Kyle that monkey wrenching should just be *absolutely* blacklisted; but you have to know when to back down from arguing or you may not get any real work done. You also still have to cater to the environment you intend to support -- developing a cross-browser library for everything since IE 6 will probably have very different constraints and gotchas than developing a module for node.js 0.6.

Comment: @speg: the problem with your suggestion, which is well known as a bad-practice among those in the community who actually know what they're doing with JavaScript, is that if you add a .trim() method to the String prototype into some library, and then a year from now, the browsers/spec ALSO add a trim, now YOUR function may be incompatibly implemented (trims differently, takes diff params, etc), and you create conflict with native behavior. Even if you feature-test before adding, you now have some code that relies on YOUR implementation but actually may get the diff native behavior.

Comment: @speg ... and not only does that create a conflict for your own code, but it's ESPECIALLY bad if your code is used by others, because you've now set landmines for them to get blown up by. There's no getting around it: this is bad-practice in almost every scenario. It's so much more likely to cause problems, the negatives FAR outweigh the ever-so-slightly-possible benefit.

Comment: @speg IRL example: for a previous employer, we had a widget (which used jquery internally) that other sites could take and embed on their own page. we had a customer complain that our widget was broken for them. I spent 3 days debugging it. Guess what I eventually found out? Way deep in their page's code, they had defined an `Array.prototype.push`. But, the problem is, THEIR implementation was slightly different from the one the browsers now all have. And jQuery relies on a real and predictable `push`. They completely broke jQuery by doing that. The proof is there, even if you won't admit it.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is "because that's how the ES committee members designed it." But specifically, the second comment on your original question (by @RobW) is exactly what they wanted to avoid.

---

Moreover, I would ask that you remove the "accepted answer" designation from @JonathonLonowski's answer, because he is clearly giving (and avidly but unwisely defending) advice (modifying built-in prototype's) which most of the web community knows to be of poor form. The *ONLY* time when it's OK to modify a built-in's prototype is when you are absolutely certain that no other code will trip over it... the only time that is true is you write 100% of all code that runs (or ever will run) on a page. The number of times that is true is so low that this advice is considered not-good-practice.